# How to Embed Video from onvif support Camera Into Html Web Page

Tags: html, web, ip-camera, onvif

i bought a new camera of axis(company name). i think it supports "onvif". i want to embed camera video/image in to my html page, how it can be possible.i am googled , but only get some c# API's and source codes.

please help me.

Comment: Pff, I'm googled too

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the particular camera: if you wan't only this exact camera, check out this [Axis support link](http://www.axis.com/global/en/support/technical-notes/live-video-on-medium-hit-rate-site) on how to embed camera stream into html. The issue with this solution is that Axis provides an ActiveX control that will work only in IE. If you don't need high fps, check out this [Axis support link](http://www.axis.com/global/en/support/technical-notes/live-snapshots) on how to get snapshots through CGI - that will work cross browser.

As for ONVIF general: if the camera supports rtsp you can retrieve the rtsp link from it an embed a generic VLC plugin in your page that loads the video feed directly from the rtsp url.

Comment: The Axis support link is no longer valid.